# What if I join the terminated(dead) thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Over here I'm trying to join a thread after it has been terminated, the code is working fine, but my question doesn't it should throw some error messageor any info?

```
public class MultiThreadJoinTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread a = new Thread(new MultiThreadJoinTest());
        a.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Begin");   
        System.out.println("End");
        a.join();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it show an error?

Comment: Look at the code for join. It checks isAlive, so it will just return.

Comment: Some people have a misconception that `join` somehow causes threads to be joined together and mixed or something. In fact, all it does is wait for the other thread to terminate if it hasn't already.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) makes no mention of throwing an exception if the thread is already terminated. In fact, the wording implies calling `join()` on a terminated thread will simply return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `Thread::join` you will notice that it calls `Thread::join(timeout)` method. And looking at the source code of this method we can see that it checks status of the thread in a loop by calling `Thread::isAlive` :

```
...
if (millis == 0 L) {
    while (this.isAlive()) {
        this.wait(0 L);
    }
} else {
    while (this.isAlive()) {
        long delay = millis - now;
        if (delay <= 0 L) {
            break;
        }

        this.wait(delay);
        now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
    }
}
...
```

so if a Thread, that you call `join` on, is terminated - `join` will just return and do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm repeating info that is already in other answers and comments, but let me try and summarize, while adding explanation.

The point of `thread.join()` is to wait for the thread to terminate. That's what it tells you in the [documentation for join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()):

> Waits for this thread to die.

Waiting for a terminated thread to terminate is pretty straightforward (!), and there seems to be no logical reason why waiting for a terminated thread to terminate should be considered an error.  You want to know when the thread finishes.  It has.

More significantly, if the caller had to ensure that a thread had not terminated before waiting for it to terminate, that would create a timing window that every caller would have to compensate for. The trivial sequence

```
 Thread t = new Thread(…);
 t.start();
 t.join();
```

would be prone to failure due to its inherent race hazard.  In other words, that would be a bad way to design `join`.

Answer (score 2):

No, Thread.join() will return instantly if the thread is already dead

Answer (score 0):

Thread will start the execution. will print Run then thread will sleep for 5 seconds and will print Begin following by End

**Output on the console:**

Run

---- 5 seconds sleep ------

Begin

End

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, which is about the behavior of ```join``` if the thread has already terminated/